# Retirar linha de arquivo XML usando Python e criar arquivo TXT com resultado

Tags: python, xml, windows

Tenho vários arquivos XML dentro de uma pasta que se chama ARQUIVOS e ela é local no Windows.

Todos arquivos XML seguem a mesma estrutura, como abaixo:

```
<catalog>
<product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
<catalog_item gender="Men's">
***<item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>***
<price>39.95</price>
<size description="Medium">
<color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
<color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
</size>
<size description="Large">
```

Gostaria de retirar deste XML a informação:

```
<price>39.95</price>
```

Ou seja, os 39.95 entre `<price>` e `</price>`

E criar outro arquivo no formato CSV ou TXT. Isso para todos os arquivos dessa pasta de forma automatizada.

Tentei criar o seguinte código:

```
search = 'print'

def check():
    datafile = open('C:\\ARQUIVOS\example.xml')
    for line in datafile:
        if search in line:
            found = </price>
            print(line)
            break
        else:
            found = price
    return found


check()
```

Não consegui passar disso, e não sei como terminar. Alguém por favor poderia me ajudar? Lembrando que são para vários xml dentro de uma pasta!

Comment: Só vai existir uma tag `<price>` por arquivo ou cada arquivo pode ter mais de dessa tag? E qual é a estrutura do arquivos de saída?

Answer (score 2):

Solução usando [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)

```
texto = """
        <catalog>
        <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
        <catalog_item gender="Men's">
        ***<item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>***
        <price>39.95</price>
        <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
        </size>
        <size description="Large">
        """
```

### Carregue o BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

### Crie a "sopa"

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(texto, 'xml')
```

### Procure o que você quer

```
>>> preco = soup.find("price")
>>> preco
<price>39.95</price>
```

Caso você queira apenas o valor, use:

```
>>> preco = soup.find("price").text
>>> preco
'39.95'
```

## Outro exemplo

Imaginando que você possui uma estrutura grande com vários preços nela, conforme abaixo:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <nome>Carro</nome>
        <preco>55000.00</preco>
    </item>
    <item>
        <nome>Moto</nome>
        <preco>25000.00</preco>
    </item>
</items>
```

Para pegar todos os preços de uma vez só, existe o `findAll`

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(texto, 'xml')
>>> precos = soup.findAll("preco")
>>> precos
[<preco>55000.00</preco>, <preco>25000.00</preco>]
```

Depois é só iterar sobre a lista

```
>>> for preco in precos:
...     print(float(preco.text))
```

Nota: transformei o valor de string para float, mas se o objetivo é salvar em disco, este não é necessário.

O resultado será:

```
55000.0
25000.0
```

Espero que ajude