# Consulta XML python não retona

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

Quero fazer uma consulta que me retorna o valor `['1961']`, no caso na "**CONSULTA 2**".

Como o arquivo possui várias linhas, eu especifiquei um pedaço do arquivo XML.
Uso essa mesma consulta "CONSULTA 2" em outros arquivos que funciona perfeitamente, mas nesse arquivo a consulta retorna erro.

O "CONSULTA 1" funciona perfeitamente mas não serve pois retorna todos os valores, especifiquei somente para mostrar que ele retorna os valores
Quero saber onde que está o erro.

Trecho do XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Documento xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Documentos />
  <CompanhiaAberta>
    <NumeroSequencial>1961</NumeroSequencial>
```

```
# CONSULTA 1
NumeroSequencial1 = []
for infos in root.iter('NumeroSequencial'):
    NumeroSequencial1.append(infos.text)
print(NumeroSequencial1)
['1961']

# CONSULTA 2
NumeroSequencial2 = []
for infoss in root:
    NumeroSequencial2.append(infoss.find('CompanhiaAberta/NumeroSequencial').text)
print(NumeroSequencial2)
```

Erro:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-55318317991e> in <module>
      6 NumeroSequencial2 = []
      7 for infoss in root:
----> 8     NumeroSequencial2.append(infoss.find('CompanhiaAberta/NumeroSequencial').text)
      9 print(NumeroSequencial2)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Solução

Utilizei o Element Objects: .iterfind('path').
Segundo documentação do `xml.etree.ElementTree`: Encontra todos os subelementos correspondentes, por nome de *tag ou caminho*. Retorna um iterável que produz todos os elementos correspondentes na ordem do documento.

```
# CONSULTA 2
NumeroSequencial2 = []
for infoss in root.iterfind('CompanhiaAberta/NumeroSequencial'):
    NumeroSequencial2.append(infoss.text)
print(NumeroSequencial2)
```

Comment: Não está claro o que você está querendo dizer. Recomendo reescrever o início da pergunta usando o ponto final para separar as setenças. Está bem confuso. De todo modo, para sair desse erro, você precisa entender pq `infoss.find('CompanhiaAberta/NumeroSequencial')` está retornando um objeto vazio. O que vc esperava que esse comando retornasse?

Comment: Lucas, reescrevi a pergunta, espero que seja compreendida, obrigado. o find ele deveria retorna o valor 1961, através da sequencia de tag, Esse mesmo tipo de consulta eu uso em outros arquivos e funciona, mas nesse caso, não entendo o motivo de não funcionar

Comment: Saulo, aplicando regex como em uma das respostas da pergunta que linko abaixo vc obtém `['1961']`. Apenas mude o regex para `xml=re.findall(r'[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+?',xml)`. Se quiser uma resposta usando o módulo `xml.etree.ElementTree` (como parece ser o caso do seu código), favor postar o XML completo e o código com as importações. Link para a pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/485705/retirar-linha-de-arquivo-xml-usando-python-e-criar-arquivo-txt-com-resultado?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Obrigado Lucas pela dicas

Comment: @Saulo Como você conseguiu resolver o problema, o ideal é colocar a solução numa resposta, não editar a pergunta com a solução

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erro:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-55318317991e> in <module>
      6 NumeroSequencial2 = []
      7 for infoss in root:
----> 8     NumeroSequencial2.append(infoss.find('CompanhiaAberta/NumeroSequencial').text)
      9 print(NumeroSequencial2)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Solução

Utilizei o Element Objects: .iterfind('path'). Segundo documentação do xml.etree.ElementTree: Encontra todos os subelementos correspondentes, por nome de tag ou caminho. Retorna um iterável que produz todos os elementos correspondentes na ordem do documento.

```
# CONSULTA 2
NumeroSequencial2 = []
for infoss in root.iterfind('CompanhiaAberta/NumeroSequencial'):
    NumeroSequencial2.append(infoss.text)
print(NumeroSequencial2)
```